# Не могу понять в чем ошибка.TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument. Ниже код (простейший калькулятор да и здесь лажаю)

Tags: python

```
 from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.config import Config

Config.set ("graphics", "resizable", 0)
Config.set ("graphics", "width", 400)
Config.set ("graphics", "height", 500)

saveInput = ""

class Calc4App(App):


    def build(self):

        bxlay = BoxLayout (orientation = "vertical")
        self.enter = TextInput (text = "", size_hint = (1, .3), font_size = 30, halign = "right", valign = "center", text_size = (400, 500* 3 ), readonly = True, background_color = [1,1,1, .8])
        bxlay.add_widget (self.enter)
        buttons = GridLayout (cols = 4, size_hint = (1, .7))

        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "7", on_press = self.calculations))
        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "8", on_press = self.calculations))
        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "9", on_press = self.calculations))
        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "x", on_press = self.calculations))

        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "4", on_press = self.calculations))
        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "5", on_press = self.calculations))
        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "6", on_press = self.calculations))
        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "-", on_press = self.calculations))

        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "1", on_press = self.calculations))
        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "2", on_press = self.calculations))
        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "3", on_press = self.calculations))
        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "+", on_press = self.calculations))

        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "0", on_press = self.calculations))
        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = ",", on_press = self.calculations))
        buttons.add_widget (Button (text = "=", on_press = self.calculations))
        bxlay.add_widget (buttons)

    def calculations(self, cifra):
        global saveInput

        if cifra.text is not "=":
            self.enter.text += cifra.text
            self.enter.text = saveInput
        else:
            try: saveInput = self.enter.text = str(eval(saveInput))
            except: saveInput = self.enter.text = ""


        return bxlay
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Calc4App().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextInput` не имеет параметров `valign/halign/text_size/background_color`

То есть, вот так выглядит создание вашего экземпляра `TextInput`:

```
self.enter = TextInput(
    size_hint=(1, 0.3),
    font_size=30,
    #halign="right",
    #valign="center",
    #text_size=(400, 500 * 3),
    readonly=True,
    #background_color=[1, 1, 1, 0.8],
)
```

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка исправилась, а при запуске программы в окне черный экран, без всего

Comment: Потому что `return bxlay` должен быть в методе `build`,  а не в методе `calculations `